# clip image from the top using css

Tags: javascript, css

I am developing an iphone app and I am using an image as a header. But for smaller iphones I want to reduce the size of the image. When I do it, it gets reduced from the bottom, but I want it to be reduced from the top.
I want to simply crop the top out of the picture by exactly 83px.
I can I do it using CSS?
I saw that there is an option to use clip but for some reason it simply not working on my image. If there are others methods from clip I would love to hear about them

This is the image btw:
[image]

Comment: `clip` is deprecated. Use `clip-path` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to apply the CSS background-position property. If you are working with this image as a background image than you should write code as;

```
div {
background-image:url('image.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center bottom;
}
```

Or If you placed it on html element in img tag, than you can write as;

```
img{
background-position: center bottom;
}
```

For the detail information about the background image position visit [this link.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-position)